# Proving a matrix is always symmetric

Tags: matrices, symmetry

$B$ is a square matrix of real numbers. Show that the matrix $BB^T$ is always symmetric.

Comment: Note that $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$

Answer (score 2):

$(B\cdot B^{t})^{t} = (B^{t})^{t}\cdot B^{t}= B\cdot B^{t}$

Comment: Are you able to justify/prove how you got this in words?

Comment: We say that a square matrix A is symmetric if $A^{t}=A$ where $A^{t}$ denotes the transpose of A. You should look up the definitions more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

$$(BB^t)^t=(B^t)^tB^t........$$

Comment: Are you able to justify/prove how you got this in words?

Comment: It follows from the definitions: $\;(AB)^t=B^tA^t\;$ for any two square matrices. Do it.